# Writing and separating a single text line in python to be written by separator in another file on multiple lines

Tags: python

I wish to arrange the names of some files each on a new line, and also have some words split by a space because right now they are written linked.

This is desired output, right now I have all of this on one line
I need every file with every result not written on a line or a single line but on multiple lines like you see below: thank you very much !!

```
File1 - Result1
File2- Result2 etc
```

I need

File1 - Result1 and then File 2 -Result 2 on a newline.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code you have right now.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to operate here would be using the `re` module, a regular expression handler implementation in Python:

```py
    import re

    s = 'File1 - Result1 File2- Result2 file3-result3 File4 -Result4'
    result = re.split('(?<=\S)[^-][ ](?=[a-zA-Z0-9])', s))
```

This will cover the need you described, even though there is always room for improvement for the expression if you refine the scope of all possible inputs.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for the answer! I am almost there!

#regex used
#result = re.split('(?<=\S)[^-][ ](?=[a-zA-Z0-9])', line)  <---- this wrote on multiple lines but with one character missing on many lines and not very correct so I searched a lot and had to ad the "$" like below:

result = re.split('(?<=\S$)[^-][ ](?=[a-zA-Z0-9])', line)   <---- this makes a very good result but now I have some words sticked together , I know the letters that precede a capital letter
for example "*****J" I need to have "***** J" and then 
NEWline1
NEWline2
NEWLine3
and I am done ! :)

Comment: I realised this is not correct at all but at least it gives you an idea, I will try something else using the edition feature, I will update you tomorrow @whtr